# Example field of characteristic zero

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, field-theory

Can you give an example of a field of characteristic zero (other than the complex numbers, real numbers and rational numbers)?

Comment: You ask lots of questions but accept few answers. Please check to accept when you get an answer that satisfies you. You can also upvote that answer, and others.

Answer (score 3):

[Rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) with real coefficients form a field of zero characteristic with usual addition and multiplication:

$$\left\{\frac{a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n}{b_0 + b_1 x + \dots + b_m x^m}\right\}$$

In this field, $\left(\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\right)^{-1} = \frac{Q(x)}{P(x)}$

Answer (score 2):

For any irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$ (of degree $> 1$), the field $\Bbb Q(\alpha) \cong \Bbb Q[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ (where $\alpha$ is a root of $p$) has characteristic $0$ and finite degree $> 1$ over $\Bbb Q$, so it does not coincide with any of $\Bbb Q, \Bbb R, \Bbb C$.

For example, taking $p(x) := x^2 + 1$ gives the field of [Gaussian rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_rational), $\Bbb Q[i]$.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider "A" like the field of the algebraic numbers.

Comment: What did you mean about  algebraic number?

Comment: @user275240 algebraic numbers are roots of rational polynomials. They also form a field of zero characteristic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Q}_p$, the completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the $p$-adic absolute value for some prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$, is a field of characteristic $0$ (it contains $\mathbb{Q}$ as a dense subset).  Interestingly (perhaps), the residue field $\mathbb{Z}_p/p\cdot \mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{F}_p$ has characteristic $p$ and we say $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has *mixed characteristic* $(0,p)$.